# Using the between function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with start and end dates in. I'm trying to work out if the dates I have fall on what row. For example my data frame is like so;

```
country startDate    endDate      weather
CHI     2022-12-29   2023-01-08    Rain
ENG     2023-01-01   2023-01-08    Cloud
GER     2023-01-02   2023-01-08    Cloud
FRA     2023-01-30   2023-02-05    Dry
```

I now want to create an indicator so i can see what country my set of dates refers to. So my list of dates is currently;

```
datestodo
2023-02-03
2023-02-04
```

So therefore I need what i am trying to write to return the row for FRA. I have tried to do this with the between argument but think im struggling/might not work as the start and end are not linked as they are in different columns

my attempt

```
activedates = between(datestodo, mydf$startDate, mydf$endDate)
```

Doesn't have to be done using the between function, a which is perfectly fine too or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TarJoe provides a base R workaround. Here is why `between()` from `dplyr` is not working - and a way to make it work.

When you run your code, the error tells you what is wrong. Care has been taken to make the error messages useful for functions in the tidyverse packages.

```
between(datestodo, mydf$startDate, mydf$endDate)

Error in `between()`:
! Can't recycle `left` (size 4) to size 2.
```

The error says that whatever you provided to the `left` argument is too long (length 4 instead of 2).

If we read the help file for `between()`, we find out what is going on. The usage of `between()` is:

```
between(x, left, right)
```

where `x` is a vector of values, and `left` and `right` are the boundary values. The inputs `left` and `right` need to be recyclable to the length of `x`, so they need to be the same length as `x` or a whole number divisor. Your `x` has a length of 2, so `left` and `right` can have either two values each or a single value that gets reused. The function cannot map four boundary values to two comparison values.

What you wanted to do was compare the start and end dates **in each row** to the two values in `datestodo` and return only those where there was a match. Here is how you do that in a `dplyr` way using the `between()` function.

```
mydf %>%
  rowwise() %>% # tells dplyr to do one row at a time, otherwise you get the same error 
  filter(any(between(datestodo, startDate, endDate))) # between returns two logical values, 
     # but filter expects one per row. any() returns true if any value is true
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `which()` to identify the row indeces of the given dates that fall between the `startDate` and `endDate` columns.

with mydf[which..., ] we then subset the rows.

base R:

```
datestodo <- as.Date(c("2023-02-03", "2023-02-04"))

mydf[which(datestodo >= mydf$startDate & datestodo <= mydf$endDate), ]
```

```
  country  startDate    endDate weather
4     FRA 2023-01-30 2023-02-05     Dry
```